# In the Spark UI, what does it mean when a task has a status of GET RESULT?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I have a Spark job which trains a model using Spark ML's logistic regression. In the Spark UI under the stage details page for a tree aggregation stage I see a few tasks with a status of "GET RESULT".

What does this status mean? What causes a task to be in this status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check [`TaskInfo`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.6/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/scheduler/TaskInfo.scala#L29) you'll see that "GET RESULT" `status` requires `gettingResult` to be set to `true` and this happens when `gettingResultTime` is not zero.

Finally `gettingResultTime` represents:

> The time when the task started remotely getting the result. Will not be set if the
>      task result was sent immediately when the task finished (as opposed to sending an
>      IndirectTaskResult and later fetching the result from the block manager).

So to summarize it means that task have finished and result is fetched from the block manager.